# subprocess.call does not wait for the process to complete

Tags: python, subprocess

Per Python documentation, `subprocess.call` should be blocking and wait for the subprocess to complete. In this code I am trying to convert few `xls` files to a new format by calling `Libreoffice` on command line. I assumed that the call to subprocess call is blocking but seems like I need to add an artificial delay after each call otherwise I miss few files in the `out` directory.

what am I doing wrong? and why do I need the delay?

```
from subprocess import call

for i in range(0,len(sorted_files)):
            args = ['libreoffice', '-headless', '-convert-to',
                    'xls', "%s/%s.xls" %(sorted_files[i]['filename'],sorted_files[i]['filename']), '-outdir', 'out']
            call(args)
            var = raw_input("Enter something: ") # if comment this line I dont get all the files in out directory
```

**EDIT** It might be hard to find the answer through the comments below. I used `unoconv` for document conversion which is blocking and easy to work with from an script.

Comment: Since you've got 4 answers chock full of comments here, let me summarize the basics: `call` is doing its job, and the problem is that `libreoffice` is just returning as soon as it tells the real program to kick off the conversion. (You verified that from the command line). So, what you really have is a LibreOffice question: How do I fire off a conversion job from the command line, and then wait for it to finish? You'll probably get a better answer to at http://ask.libreoffice.org than here.

Comment: simple hack around would be give libreoffice some extra time to complete the process, add a line time.sleep(0.4), this would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `soffice` command-line tool (which `libreoffice` is either just a link to, or a further wrapper around) is just a "controller" for the real program `soffice.bin`. It finds a running copy of `soffice.bin` and/or creates on, tells it to do some work, and then quits.

So, `call` is doing exactly the right thing: it waits for `libreoffice` to quit.

But you don't want to wait for `libreoffice` to quit, you want to wait for `soffice.bin` to finish doing the work that `libreoffice` asked it to do.

It looks like what you're trying to do isn't possible to do *directly*. But it's possible to do *indirectly*.

The [docs](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters) say that headless mode:

> … allows using the application without user interface.
>
> This special mode can be used when the application is controlled by external clients via the API.

In other words, the app doesn't quit after running some UNO strings/doing some conversions/whatever else you specify on the command line, it sits around waiting for more UNO commands from outside, while the launcher just runs as soon as it sends the appropriate commands to the app.

---

You probably have to use that above-mentioned external control API (UNO) directly.

See [Scripting LibreOffice](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Scripting) for the basics (although there's more info there about internal scripting than external), and the [API documentation](http://api.libreoffice.org) for details and examples.

But there may be an even simpler answer: [`unoconv`](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv) is a simple command-line tool written using the UNO API that does exactly what you want. It starts up LibreOffice if necessary, sends it some commands, waits for the results, and then quits. So if you just use `unoconv` instead of `libreoffice`, `call` is all you need.

Also notice that `unoconv` is written in Python, and is designed to be used as a module. If you just `import` it, you can write your own (simpler, and use-case-specific) code to replace the ["Main entrance"](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/blob/master/unoconv#L1096) code, and not use `subprocess` at all. (Or, of course, you can tear apart the module and use the relevant code yourself, or just use it as a very nice piece of sample code for using UNO from Python.)

Also, the `unoconv` page linked above lists a variety of other similar tools, some that work via UNO and some that don't, so if it doesn't work for you, try the others.

---

If nothing else works, you could consider, e.g., creating a sentinel file and using a filesystem watch, so at least you'll be able to detect exactly when it's finished its work, instead of having to guess at a timeout. But that's a real last-ditch workaround that you shouldn't even consider until eliminating all of the other options.

Comment: @abarnert, I also noticed the - vs -- but it only works for me if I use - and with -- I get error complaining file not fount and the GUI opens up which makes me think it did not understand any of the command line params. I also tried it with soffice and got same result. I generate the original xls file with a script (using xlwt) which contains some formula. I need to open the file in Excel to evaluate the formulas before reading them again with another script. (xlwt does not evaluate the formula). I am not sure if unoconv has the evaluation engine or not. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: @KamyarSouri: `unoconv` doesn't have an evaluation engine because it doesn't need one. It uses the UNO scripting API to control LibreOffice, which is what does the actual evaluation (and conversion), which is exactly what you want.

Comment: @KamyarSouri: And, taking a closer look at `unoconv`, it's actually designed to be used as a module. So, if you can't use it just by running it via `subprocess`, you don't need to tear the whole thing apart and, just `import` the module, and replace the "Main entrance" code with your own (simpler, use-case-specific) stuff.

Comment: I guess what I need is to open and save the file in libreoffice to give it a chance to evaluate the cells with formula. otherwise when I open the file from python using xlrd, these cells are empty/not evaluated. if unoconv does not evaluate the cells then cannot serve the purpose, right?

Comment: @KamyarSouri: As I already explained, `unoconv` uses UNO to open and save the files in libreoffice. It doesn't need to evaluate the cells itself because it doesn't even open the files itself. It tells LO to open and save the files, which is exactly what you want to know. And obviously LO _does_ know how to evaluate the cells. Therefore, `unoconv` will work.

Comment: I tried the `unoconv` and it did the job. thanks a lot for your answers. case closed :)

Comment: OK, cool. I've rewritten the answer to focus on the relevant part instead of giving 20 different possibilities.

Answer (score 5):

It's <strike>possible</strike> likely that `libreoffice` is implemented as some sort of daemon/intermediary process.  The "daemon" will (effectively<sup>1</sup>) parse the commandline and then farm the work off to some other process, possibly detaching them so that it can exit immediately.  (based on the `-invisible` option in the [documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters) I suspect strongly that this is indeed the case you have).

If this is the case, then your `subprocess.call` does do what it is advertised to do -- It waits for the daemon to complete before moving on.  However, it doesn't do what you want which is to wait for all of the work to be completed.  The only option you have in that scenario is to look to see if the daemon has a `-wait` option or similar.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>It is likely that we don't have an *actual daemon* here, only something which behaves similarly.  See [comments by abernert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285918/subprocess-call-does-not-wait-for-the-process-to-complete/16285977?noredirect=1#comment23310584_16285977)</sup>

Comment: I think you are right. Any idea how to synchronize with a daemon to find out if the job is done?

Comment: @KamyarSouri -- No clue.  I imagine that is a libreOffice specific question.  You might find some help on one of their forums.

Comment: As a side note, it's easy to test if it is used as a daemon.  Just issue a command which should take a long time from the commandline (e.g. open a gui).  If it returns right away, then you know you have a daemon on your hands.

Comment: I just tested what you asked. it returns very quickly but the output to terminal appears in few seconds.

Comment: It's probably not actually a daemon, but a launcher program that starts up the GUI app (if not running) and tells it to open your files and then quits. But the effect is the same. You _may_ be able to run the actual GUI app directly, but you may not want to do so.

Comment: @abarnert -- Maybe I don't know my terminology... How is that different than an "actual deamon"? :-P

Comment: @mgilson: Because a daemon backgrounds itself and keeps running, instead of sending a message to some other app and then quitting. Putting it in more familiar terms, `apachectl` is not a daemon (but `httpd` is, and that's what `apachectl` controls). The program that `libreoffice` controls may or may not be running as a daemon, but either way, `libreoffice` itself probably isn't one.

Comment: @abarnert -- I'm not sure if those were more familiar terms for me :-P, but I think I got the point anyway.  Thanks for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 0):

If libreoffice is being using an intermediary (daemon) as mentioned by @mgilson, then one solution is to find out what program it's invoking, and then directly invoke it yourself.

Comment: I don't have an up-to-date linux box with LO on it, but the way its predecessor OO.o worked was that the real GUI program was named `soffice.bin`, the launcher program was `soffice`, and `openoffice` was just a symlink to `soffice`. And launching `soffice.bin` directly worked just like running `firefox-bin` instead of `firefox`. Which means it fires up a new GUI that does not exit after finishing your job, it sits around and waits for the user to hit `^Q`. Which is why I said "You _may_ be able to run the actual GUI app directly, but you may not want to do so."

Comment: If the launcher program sits around and waits for the user to exit, then there wouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: I'm not sure. It sounds like he wants to use LO to "convert a few .xls files" and then quit (or at least notify him) when it's done. There may be a way to do that with command-line args, but there may not, in which case this is only part of the solution.

Comment: @abarnert -- Yeah.  It looks like (if that's the case), then he could just use the fact that `-convert-to` seems like it will take a list of files.

Comment: @mgilson: I was hoping it (either the launcher, or the real app) had some command-line args to "do these things and then exit". If that works, that's probably the simplest answer for the OP.

Comment: Oops, it looks like that's exactly what the OP was trying to do, and it didn't work…